# Configurable validation rule

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, record-type

I need to write a validation rule on case so that cases of record type **A,B,C,D,E** cannot be created for Accounts of record type **F**.
Can i create this validation rule in configurable way by storing case record types **A,B,C,D,E** in any hierarchy custom setting, label etc. which can be used in the validation rule.

```
AND(
    OR(
        RecordType.DeveloperName ="A",
        RecordType.DeveloperName ="B",
        RecordType.DeveloperName ="C",
        RecordType.DeveloperName ="D",
        RecordType.DeveloperName ="E"
    ),
    Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "F"
)
```

Comment: AND(
    CONTAINS( $Setup.Hierarchy_Custom_Setting__c.Recordtype__c , RecordType.DeveloperName ),
    Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "F"
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use only hierarchy custom settings in validation rules.

```
$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomSettingFieldName__c
```

So your formula for validation rule will look like:

```
AND(
    OR(
        RecordType.DeveloperName = $Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomSettingFieldNameA__c,
 ...
```